# OCR implementation error-java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "png_set_longjmp_fn" referenced by "liblept.so"

Tags: android, tess-two

I am using tesseract library in my code for OCR implementation.But find the above error(mentioned in title).Tried with new tess-two library in the link:https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two.
But still same issue.Isue found **only** in samsung s3 and s4 mini devices..Please help me.I am searching for the issue past few days.

I am using Android studio for the project.

Any help welcomed.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the tess-two code, you need to re-build the project by following the [build instructions](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#building).

In particular, you need to be sure to re-run the `ndk-build` step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It works fine.as you mentioned it was due to the error in building steps.Thanks a lot.

Comment: My problem was with the step android update.Anyone can use this if needed.The ecorrect usage of android update command is:androi update project --target 1 --path<project-path> where project-path is the path of folder which contains your project.Thanks.